# How to create a empty layout to show confirmation message, when the user clicks on confirmation link through devise Gem. in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I used Devise gem for User authentication in my Rails App.now i have back-end for the sys admin role users.after confirmation he can login to the Application.

but,now I have Customer with user_type Customer.now, for them i should not show login form once they click on Confirmation link.for that how to create a layout to show only confirmation Message for the Customers.

Comment: You should read the docs more and try googling a bit- https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-custom-layouts

Answer (score 0):

On link Click you need to perform action on controlle like -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def confirmation
   render layout 'confirmations' 
  end
end
```

and in your view/layouts create new html named confirmations.html.erb